# Install GDAL extension in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, gdal, extensions

I am trying to install the GDAL extension (I want to use ECW files in GeoServer).  So here is what I did so far:

1) downloaded the GDAL extension and extracted to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.3.4\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib

2) downloaded GDAL data zip and extracted to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.3.4\gdal_data

made GDAL_DATA environment variable to this folder.

3) downloaded the native libraries and extracted to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.3.4\gdal_native

added this folder to the Path environment variable.

4) restarted GeoServer.

I was trying to follow this guide: [geoserver GDAL guide](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html)

but it's not really clear...

I can't see any result after all these steps, not even an error message...
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Assuming you have everything downloaded have you set the environment variable GDAL_DRIVER_PATH?

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to get the GDAL plugins to work until I uninstalled OSGeo4W and deleted the GDAL files in C:\OSGeo4W directory. GeoServer still works alongside QGIS standalone version with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter Geoserver and go to Stores/Add new one. You might see more rasters formats displayed. This is one possible check to see if you have installed the plug-in.

In addition, just to improve what you have said above:

1) Download the GDAL geoserver extension for your version, i.e. v. 2.6.0:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.6.0/extensions/geoserver-2.6.0-gdal-plugin.zip

These are the .jar files and must be extracted to the .\WEB-INF\lib folder within your geoserver path installation

2) Download the GDAL 'CRS definitions' for your imageio-ext version, see below:

If your .jar files from above, step 1, are named like 'imageio-ext-*-1.1.10' then you may go to the v. 1.1.10:

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.10/native/gdal/

create 'GDAL_DATA' as environment variable and populate it with the folder path where you put these files, or use any other folder with a current GDAL installation (but check versions)

3) Download the native libraries for Linux:
http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.10/native/gdal/linux/

or windows (check your MSVC version):
http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.10/native/gdal/windows/

Put these native libraries into a folder and add it to the PATH variable

4) Re-start Geoserver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my Docker container based Ubuntu 14.04 Oracle Java 7 with JAI 1.1.3, ImageIO 1.1, GDAL 1.10.1 and extensions: ogr, gdal, printing, importer.
Run docker:

```
$ docker run -d winsent/geoserver
```

Or look at the Dockerfile on the details of installation https://hub.docker.com/r/winsent/geoserver/~/dockerfile/

Comment: docker doesn't work very well on Windows, which is the platform the user has, so I can't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

We have just published Geoserver 2.16.1 with GDAL 2.1.1
at https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/geosystr/geosys-geoserver

FYI

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".